# how do I turn off webcam brightness auto-adjust?

Tags: brightness, webcam

My Logitech web camera adjusts brightness automatically and I don't like it. I wonder how I could turn this feature off from ubuntu. 
I downloaded `v4l2ucp` that seems to be a program to do just that, but interestingly most of its settings are grey (can't set) the automatic gain/brightness checkbox is clickable, however, but it does not work (the camera still adjusts to brightness automatically).

I don't quite know what to do at this point. It is possible to turn this off, right?